# ORA-12541: TNS : no listening process

Tags: listener, tns, oracle21c

I’m actually using oracle 21c express.
The problem is the fact the TNS service "OracleOraDB21HomeTNSListener" is missing in all services. When installing oracle 21c I can notice an error message which is « An error occurred while configuring Oracle XE listener ». What’s the real problem here?

Normally after searching i understood that this problem occurred when the TNS service is not running then you just have to start it in your services to resolve it. But I can’t turn the service on because the service is missing.